# Updating the value of an item in ArrayAdapter of Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-arrayadapter

I have a list of the form:

```
var list = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1);
list.Add("George");
list.Add("Abraham");
```

in a Xamarin Android app.

How can I modify the first item of the list from "George" to "Donald" (without creating a new list with correct item)?

Something like:

```
list[0] = "Donald"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the method `NotifyDataSetChanged` after updating the ItemSource of **ListView** .

The definition of `NotifyDataSetChangedin` the Android's documentation is as follows

> Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.

```
list[0] = "Donald"      
list.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

#### Update

You could create the Adapter with a string list like following

```
List<string> ItemsSource = new List<string>() {"George","Abraham" };
ItemsSource.Add("Lucas");
var list = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1,ItemsSource);
```

```
var adapter = listView.Adapter as ArrayAdapter;
adapter.Remove(s[0]);
adapter.Insert("Donald",0);
adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

#### Option 2

You could create a custom adapter (subclass of BaseAdapter) so that you can set the value directly .

Comment: The main problem is that `list[0]` is undefined. No indexers are defined for ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. Changing `ItemsSource` has no effects on `list`. It seem they have different buffers.

Comment: This works but it has something bad. What if two items of a list are the same and you want to change the second one? I think that solution does not work for that. Suppose both items of the list is "George" and you want change the second one.

Comment: So  as I said you could use custom adapter .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224322/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-minimus-heximus).

Answer (score 1):

We can use clear method of adapter and then can add list again.

```
var list = new List<string> { "George", "Abraham" };

var adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, list);

list[0] = "Donald";

adapter.Clear();
adapter.AddAll(list);
```